# The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Users'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly

Tags: asp.net

I have some problems. I make web site and load it to hosting server "somee.com". All work correct, but after last update web site on hosting i get error "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Users'.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.". I define that the problem occur with the new table "Users". All queries to old tables work well. The table "Users" be on database on hosting server exactly. I try to create new tables and make simple queries to them like "Select SomeText FROM TestTable". All of them works fine at my computer. But when i transfer changes to hosting - get the similar exception.
That it can be?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is check the connection string: http://somee.com/doka/DoHelpTopics.aspx?docode=false&thnid=91